# Using Jenkins Parameter In Kubernetes Yaml

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, yaml, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use my Jenkins Pipeline parameter to change name in .yaml file. How can i achieve that?

In Jenkins, my parameter name is defined as **NEWCLAIM**

yaml file

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ${params.NEWCLAIM}
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

I get errors when i use like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jenkins you can use [readYaml](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readyaml-read-yaml-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) and [writeYaml](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#writeyaml-write-a-yaml-from-an-object-or-objects) for that.If you use a scripted pipeline aka a Jenkinsfile, I would do the following:

```bash
pipeline {
   stages {
      stage('Manipulate Yaml file') {
         def config = readYaml file: "path/to/your/config.yml"
         config.metadata.name = params.NEWCLAIM
         writeYaml file: "path/to/your/config.yml", data: config
      }
   }
}
```

Please consider to set permissions correctly in order to write the file.

Comment: Thanks, worked! also "Pipeline Utility Steps" plugin needed